# Can anyone give a good example of using org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli programmatically?

Tags: api, maven-3

I'm trying to create an intelliJ plugin that needs to execute maven targets on the current project.  All the talk in the intertubes recommends using the MavenEmbedder.  Good luck with that.  The 2.0.4 version isn't well supported and there are no references for how to use it.

I gave it a whirl and ran into a wall where the embedder had not been initialized with all the fields it needs.  Reflective private member injection? Awesome!  Why would anyone need an obvious way to initialize an object?

It seems a few people are using a 2.1 version with some success.  I have been unable to find that in a jar or even sources.

I went and checked out the 3.0 version of the embedder project: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0-beta-3/maven-embedder/  It does away with the MavenEmbedder object all together and seems to only support access through the main or doMain methods on MavenCli.  Has anyone used these methods and can give some advice?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yeah, the's not much in the way of documentation of MavenCli. The API is significatly simpler but i'd still like some examples. Here's one that works...

```java
MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
int result = cli.doMain(new String[]{"compile"},
        "/home/aioffe/workspace/MiscMaven",
        System.out, System.out);
System.out.println("result: " + result);
```

It takes a dir and runs the 'compile' phase...

Comment: If anyone else comes across this, you need to add three dependencies in order for Maven to fetch dependencies that aren't already in your local workstation's repo.  "org.apache.maven:maven-embedder:3.0.5", "org.sonatype.aether:aether-connector-wagon:1.13.1", and "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.4" (exact versions may vary with future Maven releases).  It drove me crazy figuring that out... and the embedded Maven documentation is absolutely non-existent.

Comment: Thanks soo much @StevePerkins! FYI and BTW, for maven 3.1 these versions worked for me : "org.apache.maven:maven-embedder:3.1.0", "org.eclipse.aether:aether-connector-wagon:0.9.0.M2", "org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http:2.5".

Comment: For me (maven 3.0.4) this is working: `org.apache.maven:maven-embedder:3.0.4`, `org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-http-lightweight:2.5` and `org.sonatype.aether:aether-connector-wagon:1.13.1`

Comment: for maven 3.6.1, you will need slf4j-simple to see logs, maven-embedder and maven-compat to make it work!

Comment: For those behind proxy, you would need additional dependencies aether-connector-basic:1.0.2.v20150114, aether-transport-wagon:1.0.2.v20150114,wagon-http:2.9,wagon-provider-api:2.9,wagon-http-lightweight:2.9

Comment: Getting an error: `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set.`

Comment: This works, but the maven build logs are going to error stream and no log messages in the standard output stream. Any information ?

Answer (score 14):

Working maven configuration for `maven 3.6.3`

### Code

```
MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
System.setProperty("maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory", workingDirectory);
cli.doMain(new String[]{"compile"}, workingDirectory, System.out, System.err);
```

### Dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5995 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- enable logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: For those behind proxy, you would need additional dependencies aether-connector-basic:1.0.2.v20150114, aether-transport-wagon:1.0.2.v20150114,wagon-http:2.9,wagon-provider-api:2.9,wagon-http-lightweight:2.9

Answer (score 6):

The dependency matrix information for provided scopes and dynamically acquired components can be a bit confusing.  It was for me, since it appeared to me that I got all the required items by direct or transitive dependency, but then remote resolution didn't work.

I wanted to jump to Maven 3.3.3 (latest as of 2015-05-25).  I got it working without the sisu errors that presented when I tried to optimistically update to current versions of things specified here (and elsewhere).  This is a project with a tag that worked with the example specified as of today using JDK8.

https://github.com/mykelalvis/test-maven-embedder/tree/20150525-working

Relevant deps (SLF4J is just so I can see the logs)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-connector-basic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.v20150114</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-transport-wagon</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.v20150114</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-provider-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-http-lightweight</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Running this is:

```
rm -r ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/
mvn exec:java
```

Probably should have made it a unit test of some sort.

If someone has a superior solution for embedded Maven 3.3.3 (i.e. came up with a smaller or more range-oriented set of required dependencies), please post them.

Comment: this is the best answer! it works for all behind proxy.

Answer (score 0):

to build on the comment from @StevePerkins, and using maven version 3.1.0,

I had to exclude the transitive dependency from aether-connector-wagon to wagon-provider-api to get it working.

pom.xml:

```
(...)
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
    <artifactId>aether-connector-wagon</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0.M2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-provider-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
(...)
```

and here is a java example:

```
(...)
MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();

ByteArrayOutputStream baosOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream baosErr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

PrintStream out = new PrintStream(baosOut, true);
PrintStream err = new PrintStream(baosErr, true);

cli.doMain( new String[] { "clean" }, new File("."), out, err );

String stdout = baosOut.toString("UTF-8");
String stderr = baosErr.toString("UTF-8");
(...)
```

full example [here](https://github.com/cthiebaud/shakuntala/blob/57f1ba7ea3fc22011747c39720ad7f8fc854c317/src/test/java/net/aequologica/shakuntala/EventSpyImplBaseTest.java)

Comment: For those behind proxy, you would need additional dependencies aether-connector-basic:1.0.2.v20150114, aether-transport-wagon:1.0.2.v20150114,wagon-http:2.9,wagon-provider-api:2.9,wagon-http-lightweight:2.9

Answer (score 0):

There is a dependency matrix for each version of maven-embedder, e.g. for 3.2.5: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-embedder/dependencies.html

Based on that I had to use `org.apache.maven:maven-embedder:jar:3.2.5`, `org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.2.5`, and `org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:2.8`.

It also fixes dependency on very old Guava library, since this version uses 18.0.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency list for Maven Embedded 3.6.3 version that works in my Spring Boot 2.3  project (JDK8 or JDK 11 runtime):

```
    <!-- Maven Embedder -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-connector-basic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-transport-wagon</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.usefultoys</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-toys</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

The Maven CLI command looks like to:

```
    // Maven CLI to execute Maven Commands
    MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
    int result = cli.doMain(args, workingDirectory,
                    org.usefultoys.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getInfoPrintStream(LOGGER),
                    org.usefultoys.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getErrorPrintStream(LOGGER));
```

HTH

Comment: Not working for me java 8 spring boot 2.1.7 
But I got further :)
Still something missing though.