# Maven CLI - sync project dependecies

Tags: java, maven, command-line-interface

I have a maven project. I want to **synchronize / download all dependencies** to make my project to be resolved in this sense. I want to make it from java, using `Maven CLI API`.

There is a method that supposed to be same as "mvn clean validate":

```
public static void syncProjectDeps(String projectPath) {

    MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
    int result = cli.doMain(new String[]{"clean", "validate"}, projectPath, System.out, System.out);

    System.out.println(result);

}
```

But it fails with the following exception (**no connector available to access repository central**):

```
INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR]   The project com.mycompany.common:configuration:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT (C:\store\myproject\java\trunk\configuration\pom.xml) has 1 error
 ...
 No connector available to access repository central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

It seems it does not use `<repositories>` I already have in my projects's `pom.xml`.

What is the way make it work?

Comment: What about trying to set it in settings.xml. If you display the effective pom do you see those repositories?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It seems I found the answer.

The answer were here:

[Can anyone give a good example of using org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli programattically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206679/can-anyone-give-a-good-example-of-using-org-apache-maven-cli-mavencli-programatt)

And here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/daisy-pipeline-dev/tubf3KXClM4

http://code.google.com/p/phloc-parent-pom/source/browse/trunk/pom.xml?r=47

Basically you should end up with this pom.xml (all about dependencies!):

```
<!-- maven api-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206679/can-anyone-give-a-good-example-of-using-org-apache-maven-cli-mavencli-programatt -->
            <groupId>org.sonatype.aether</groupId>
            <artifactId>aether-connector-wagon</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId> <!-- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/daisy-pipeline-dev/tubf3KXClM4 -->
            <version>2.1</version>     <!-- http://code.google.com/p/phloc-parent-pom/source/browse/trunk/pom.xml?r=47 -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then, if you have an error like:

```
Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.mycompany.common:commons:pom:2.0.6
```

**then make sure you use right version for your parent project**. Parent should have the same version that real LOCAL root pom.xml has.

If you still have that error then the path to your parent like this:

```
 <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
```

This is actually default value. But in your case it might be

```
 <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
```

if you have deeper folder structure (like I had)

---

- my client code is:

  ```
      System.setProperty("user.home", "C:\\my"); // ~/.m2/repository lives here    
      MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();

     // THIS IS IMPORTANT AS WELL  !!!
     int result = cli.doMain(
                  new String[]{"-DincludeScope=runtime", "dependency:copy-dependencies", "clean", "validate"},
                  projectPath,
                  System.out,
                  System.out);
  ```

It creates: `c:/.m2/repository` folder. But it is empty for now.

Answer (score 1):

Connector for remote http repositories is named [wagon](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/), configure your project like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
        <artifactId>aether-connector-wagon</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-http-lightweight</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```