# Maven embedder causing build failure

Tags: java, maven-3, wildfly-8

I have setup a project that deploys to a Wildfly AS fine using Maven

```
wildfly:deploy
```

I was looking to implement calling Maven3 from Java using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206679/can-anyone-give-a-good-example-of-using-org-apache-maven-cli-mavencli-programatt) but by including the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

the deploy phase fails. Why is this happening and is there a solution?

Comment: Why would you like to call Maven from Java? Furthermore what does `the deploy phase fails` mean? messages ? How did you call it etc.?

Comment: @khmarbaise I want to enable the building/downloading of a Java client over a J2E web server that is customised for each user allowing offline usage. I add the goal in eclipse of wildfly:deploy. That works fine without the dependency but fails with it. The failure is just the standard maven build failed message stating that it failed on the deploy cycle. I have managed to get a different plugin working as I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get this plugin working but got the maven invoker plugin to work

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```