# Running maven goals from Java without a Maven executable installed on the machine

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, maven-embedder

I am trying to build a project to checkout code from SCM and build it using maven. Is there a way we can achieve running maven goals from java without a maven home being provided(no maven installation). For SVN, I am using svnkit to achieve the same. For maven, I tried using the below 2 options.

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0-beta-3/maven-embedder/
[Can anyone give a good example of using org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli programattically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206679/can-anyone-give-a-good-example-of-using-org-apache-maven-cli-mavencli-programatt)

For both the above options, I need to have a maven installation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, just include the jar in your project and the following, to compile code:

```
MavenCli cli = new MavenCli();
int result = cli.doMain(new String[]{"compile"},
        "workspace/MiscMaven",
        System.out, System.out);
System.out.println("result: " + result);
```

Per a comment, here's how you add the dependency to your project. This does **not** install maven on your system, merely includes the JARs in your project build:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
    <artifactId>aether-connector-basic</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.v20150114</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
    <artifactId>aether-transport-wagon</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.v20150114</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-provider-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-http-lightweight</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi hd1. MavenCli would require a maven installation to run rite?. I tried running the above code and got the below error. Exception in thread 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.EntityReplacementMap
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)

Comment: Also have the below  in my pom file.'<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-embedder</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.aether</groupId>
            <artifactId>aether-connector-wagon</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-http-lightweight</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>'