# Execute Maven plugin command from Java code

Tags: java, maven, processbuilder

As the title suggests I was wondering if there was a way to execute a maven command like this from Java code ...

`mvn --dependency:get -Dartifact=groupid.com:artifactId:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`

I can run this from the command line but when I try to run this using the Java ProcessBuilder I get

> Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option:
> --dependency:get

It looks like the ProcessBuilder can't find the maven-dependency-plugin.

Here is my code snippet, note that the `mvn --version` command works but the command that requires the plugin does not :(

```
    private static void RunCommand() {
        //String command = "mvn --version";
        String command = "mvn --dependency:get -Dartifact=groupid.com:artifactId:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT";
        try {
            boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("windows");
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);  
            if (isWindows) {
                builder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", command);
            } else {
                builder.command("sh", "-c", command);
            }
            Process process = builder.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("\nExited with error code : " + exitCode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

Is there anyway to tell ProcessBuilder where to find the maven plugin?

Comment: maybe you could try MavenCli - check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206679/can-anyone-give-a-good-example-of-using-org-apache-maven-cli-mavencli-programmat

Comment: I was looking into that, and other similar questions, but I could not develop a Maven Embedder command that was equivalent to the mvn command I posted in the question. What or how would you structure the cli.doMain args to match the dependency:get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

`mvn dependency:get`

[reference](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#dependency:get)

Comment: Thanks, when I ran the 'command' at the command line I was actually in a GIT Bash command line environment. I tried the command at a DOS prompt and it failed as above. So must be a difference between DOS and BASH. Anyways, removing the '--' gets me to the next error, not resolving the remote repository correctly, but that will be a another topic.